# laravel-react (inertia/vita) - import react dnd-kit

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs, dnd-kit

I've setup a very fresh and unmodified page with laravel/breeze starter kit. Laravel using vite plugin, inertia and react. Everything got setup by laravel:breeze starter kit.
Now for my frontend I need to work with the react dnd-kit but im struggling to import it into the ecosystem.

First I installed it with `npm install @dnd-kit/core` but then I dont know where to implement this lines of code

```
import {DndContext} from '@dnd-kit/core';

import {Draggable} from './Draggable';
import {Droppable} from './Droppable';
```

I tried a lot of locations, how I have understand it, I should implement it in vite.config.js but when I add it there the visual studio code ide tells me its wrong.

Comment: Read [here](https://docs.dndkit.com/introduction/getting-started)